# one row insert into mysql from a loop php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have a loop where I need to get the elements and then I need to insert each element in mysql table but this code is able to insert only 1 element.(p.s. The variable is loaded with min 4 element).

Why I'm not able to insert multiple element with this loop?

Please I need it to know urgently.Thanks

```
function addmijloc(){

foreach ($_SESSION["mijloc"] as $check)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO isu_mijloace (`nr_rap_ext_mijl`, `mijloc`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['nrraport']."', '".$check."')";
if(mysql_query($sql)) 
    {
    $mijloace="ok"; 
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<script>alert("Tabela mijloace eronata");</script>';  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can do batch insert `insert into table (,) values (..,..), (..,..),..`

Comment: so I need to insert the '".$_SESSION['nrraport']."' in () and then '".$check."' in other ()?

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors? Have you tried checking how many times your loop iterates? Do you get any alerts at the browser? how many?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to get what result you get when you print_r($check) in you loop?

Comment: if I use the loop without insert query then I receive the data from the array.So it's ok without the mysql query

Comment: if you get your data in your whille print_r($check) then use this array in query.For eg.$check['name'],$check['age']

Comment: so how can I do this?

Comment: Let me explain you I use this code for load my array variable: session_start();

$_SESSION["mijloc"][]=$_GET["mij"];
foreach ($_SESSION["mijloc"] as $check)
{
 echo $check.'<br>';
 
 
}

Comment: and then I need to use the $_SESSION["mijloc"][] to insert each element in mysql

Comment: dont use echo but use echo "<pre>";print_r($check);

Comment: when I use print_r I have number 1 at last for each element

Comment: eg: Mijloace de prima interventie1

Comment: what exact data you get when you print_r in array can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_SESSION["mijloc"] as $check=>$value)
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO isu_mijloace (`nr_rap_ext_mijl`, `mijloc`) VALUES      ('".$_SESSION['nrraport']."', '".$value."')";
  mysql_query($sql);
  if(mysql_query($sql))
   {
    $mijloace="ok"; 
   }
    else
   {
    echo '<script>alert("Tabela mijloace eronata");</script>';  
   }
 }
```